# Cannot drop the distribution database 'distribution' on managed instance

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database, database-migration, transactional-replication

I am not able to delete the distributor and distribution database because it is saying that it is currently in use on Azure Managed Instance.I tried transactional replication between azure managed instance to azure sql vm. Then I was trying to delete replication ,publisher,subscriber and distributor.I was successful in dropping replication,publisher and subscriber but my distributor is not getting deleted.
I am trying to do:

`exec sp_dropdistributor @no_checks = 1, @ignore_distributor = 1`

Then I got this below statement as error:

> Msg 21122, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_dropdistributiondb,
>   Line 125 [Batch Start Line 6]
>
> Cannot drop the distribution database 'distribution' because it is
>   currently in use.

I even tried to disable distributor using Disable publishing and distributor wizard.The process was unsuccessful.
What steps should I now follow to delete my distributor?

Comment: Please Help me with this as fast as possible. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Ankita, can you please file support request for this issue to be troubleshooted? "New support request" option on Managed Instance Portal blade will guide you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue. Eventually I was able to drop the database via the Azure Portal.

Go to your SQL managed instance, scroll down in the "Overview" tab, open the distribution database and delete the database via the button on the top.

The proces which prevented deletion of the database via sp_dropdistributor will keep on running. It can't be killed via KILL. Haven't gotten any feedback on what to do about that yet.